# "Are you sure?" via a messagebox in powershell

Tags: forms, xaml, powershell

Goodmorning developers,

I am trying to make a delete function in powershell. I want to have something like this:

```
  function deleteEnv(){
    $result = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Are you sure?''Yes', 'No' 'Info')
    if(yes){
     //Delete
}

else {
//do nothing
}
}
```

When I click the delete button a message box must be shown first with the two buttons yes or no. If yes then delete else do nothing. How can I do this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$result = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Are you sure?' , "Info" , 4)
if ($result -eq 'Yes') {
    do stuff
}
```

Additional reading: http://powershell-tips.blogspot.com.by/2012/02/display-messagebox-with-powershell.html

Answer (score 0):

An 2022 Update:

In addition to  @4c74356b41's answer:

If you want to use the modern Windows style when calling from Powershell, in Windows 8,10,11 -- the visual styles need to be enabled, and Reflection is not required:

```powershell
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles();

$result = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Are you sure?", "Title", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Question)

if ($result -eq "Yes") {
    # do stuff
}
```

Cleaner, you can pass the references beforehand to variables (and in `Powershell ISE` which is preinstalled on any windows, you get code completion with CTRL+SPACE after the `::` to list the options)

```powershell
$mb = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]
$mbIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]
$mbBtn = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles();

$result = $mb::Show("Are you sure?", "Title", $mbBtn::YesNo, $mbIcon::Question)
Echo $result

If ($result -eq "Yes") {
    # do stuff
}
Else {
    # do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding naming a function you should read `Get-Help about_Functions`:

> Function Names
>
> You can assign any name to a function, but functions that you share with
> others should follow the naming rules that have been established for all
> PowerShell commands.
>
> Functions names should consist of a verb-noun pair where the verb
> identifies the action that the function performs and the noun identifies
> the item on which the cmdlet performs its action.

Here is an example function for you case:

```ps
function Remove-Something ($object) {
    if (-not $object) {
        # Nothing to delete
        Write-Warning "No object given as parameter. Nothing to delete."
        return
    }
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $text = "Do you want to delete?"
    $caption = "Delete..."
    $buttons = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNo
    $icon = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Question
    $defaultButton = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton]::Button2 # default: no - avoid accidential deletion
    #Show the MessageBox:
    $YouAreSure = @{"Yes"=$true;"No"=$false}."$([System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($text,$caption,$buttons,$icon,$defaultButton))"
    if ($YouAreSure) {
    Write-Output "It should now delete $object"
        # insert delete commands here
    }
}
```

Start your function with `Remove-Something "that needs to be removed"`

If you need a different MessageBox this might help

```
$icon = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::None
$icon = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information
$icon = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Question
$icon = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Warning
$icon = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error

$buttons = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK
$buttons = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OKCancel
$buttons = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::RetryCancel
$buttons = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::AbortRetryIgnore
$buttons = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNo
$buttons = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNoCancel


$defaultButton = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton]::Button1
$defaultButton = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton]::Button2
$defaultButton = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton]::Button3
```

More details about MessageBox can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox